# Solving linear congruence, need help

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I solve $5x+1 \equiv 2 \mod 6$ so that I receive $x \equiv 5 \mod 6$?

I'm very confused.  I know how to solve if there wasn't $a +1$ after the $5x$.  I just want to understand how I can go from the first congruence to the second.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$5x+1\equiv 2\pmod 6$ is the same as $5x\equiv 1\pmod 6$ which is equivalent to $-x\equiv 1\pmod 6$ or $x\equiv -1\pmod 6$ which leads to $x\equiv 5\pmod 6$